# Client server framework for tablets

Tags: java, objective-c, websocket, client-server, multiplayer

I need to create a multiplayer game for tablets, and have been looking around for a client server framework that I can work with in Java on the server side, and Objective C or Java for the clients. The game is not action intense, and will be used by a handful of players at a time, and not by millions.

I looked at WebSockets, but it seems that its target is browsers rather then tablets, although there's also [a framework for doing Objective C](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient) Objective C on the client side.

I have quite a bit of experience with web applications, but have never done client server games. Any idea where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Many real time games, e.g. first person shooters, wrote their own custom protocol based on UDP.

It used to be that non real time games would generally write their own protocol directly over TCP, however nowadays it's quite common to use HTTP for non real time games. While HTTP is most commonly used in browsers to carry HTML pages, it is actually general enough to be used in almost any server-client situations where you want RESTful property. Use POST to create, GET to read, PUT to update, and DELETE to delete, and you get the whole CRUD; use URLs to identify resources; and cookie to keep track of state; HTTP Auth for authentication; and HTTPS to prevent snooping. Websockets adds server-initiated push to the HTTP protocol. The advantage of using HTTP is that it's behavior is well understood and well standardized (therefore, lots of high quality prewritten module supporting the protocol). Another advantage is that HTTP is language and device agnostic, therefore porting your game to the browser or another platform should become fairly straightforward with regards to the networking access. HTTP also have well understood and well supported techniques to let your game scale, load balance, cache, etc, something you don't get with writing your own application-layer protocol.

It is rarely necessary nor advisable to develop your own application protocol, but if you need to, you can write a custom application layer protocol directly over TCP. This is usually highly specialized, so without knowing what the type of the game is and what it's networking requirement, I wouldn't be able to tell you if you'd benefit from a TCP-level framework.

Comment: Thanks, Lie. So I guess you're recommending HTTP, and maybe WebSockets? Is there a framework that does WebSockets fully -- at least on the server side? Maybe there's a cloud based solution?